# The components in Magento are designed in classes or objects?

Tags: magento2, design

I'm practicing drawing some basic diagrams in Magento. I have completed the use case diagram, I wonder how to draw a class diagram. I see some classes in the directory model in the modules so they have too many attributes and methods. So I think I cannot draw class diagram with some classes.

Can someone explain to me how the components in Magento are designed in classes or objects? Can you give me some examples?

Comment: You means the ui components? If you are Vietnamese, let's keep in touch on FB.

Comment: yes,Can you give me your fb?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/trong.phung240596

Comment: Ok, keep add the question, I will reply tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Firstable, there is nothing in the world "designed in class or object". We use another term: **design pattern**.

In short,

> A design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in software design.

But I recommend you have a read to the following articles:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/choosing-the-right-design-pattern
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315000/how-to-study-design-patterns

### There are a lot of **design patterns** in this world, and Magento 2 is using the following:

- Composite Pattern
- Strategy Pattern
- Factory Method Pattern
- Observer Pattern
- Object Manager (which consist of 11+ Design Patterns)
- Decorator Pattern
- Proxy Pattern

You can also check this: https://www.slideshare.net/MaksymPronko/key-insights-into-development-design-patterns-for-magento-2-magento-live-uk

### But if you are talking to database structure in Magento, then these articles are good to start:

- https://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1/
- http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-eav-database-structure/

Finally, welcome to Magento 2 :)